# Umbraco - ContentTypeService failed to find a content type

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I created a document type named "Home", created some content of this document type and some others underneath it. I have now renamed to "HomePage" but now greeted with the following error on any page of the website.

I have tried republishing the website, updating the template name to 'HomePage'... have no idea where its getting the reference to 'Home' - The Node in DB appears to have been updated, so must be something else (cache has been cleared as far as I know but clearing the Temp folder and umbraco.config). Other notes, latest version of Umbraco, using MVC.

**ContentTypeService failed to find a content type with alias "Home".**

Comment: Seems to work now - I think it was fixed by deleting the XML previews in the database and taking the home page out of preview mode!... I think anyway

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly the same, for me it was caused by an old reference in App_Data\Umbraco.config not present anymore as a document type. Republishing the whole site and therefore recreating Umbraco.config fixed it.

Comment: Yep, just delete the GUID-named preview folder with the name of the plugin in it.  Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had to save the Document Type again.

Comment: For me it went away when I cleaned the umbraco bin, it's not the first time bin items causes an issue